# Can Selective Adaptation be used to get equipment or enchantments?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Selective Adaptation](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Selective%20Adaptation), a green sorcery, says:

> Reveal the top seven cards of your library. Choose from among them a card with flying, a card with first strike, and so on for double strike, deathtouch, haste, hexproof, indestructible, lifelink, menace, reach, trample, and vigilance. Put one of the chosen cards onto the battlefield, the other chosen cards into your hand, and the rest into your graveyard.

Will this work for equipment and auras? For example, [Basilisk Collar](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Basilisk%20Collar) says

> Equipped creature has deathtouch and lifelink.

If I understand keywords correctly, Basilisk Collar *gives* Lifelink to equipped creature, but it doesn't *have* lifelink.

So - can I put Basilisk Collar on the battlefield with Selective Adaptation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Basilisk Collar *gives* lifelink to equipped creature, but it doesn't *have* lifelink.

Correct, therefore Selective Adaptation cannot fetch Basilisk Collar. For example, if an unequipped Basilisk Collar is animated with [Karn, the Great Creator](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Karn%2C%20the%20Great%20Creator)'s +1 ability:

> +1: Until your next turn, up to one target noncreature artifact becomes an artifact creature with power and toughness each equal to its converted mana cost.

the collar itself won't have deathtouch.

While Selective Adaptation can't fetch Basilisk Collar itself, there are [some non-creature non-vehicles which have either indestructible or hexproof](https://scryfall.com/search?q=fo%3A%2F%5E%28hexproof%7Cindestructible%29%2F+-t%3A%2Fcreature%7Cvehicle%2F&unique=cards&as=grid&order=name) and therefore *can* be fetched with Selective Adaptation, for example:

- [Darksteel Axe](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Darksteel%20Axe), an indestructible equipment
- [Lotus Field](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lotus%20Field), a hexproof land
- [Nine Lives](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Nine%20Lives), a hexproof enchantment

(Credit to [mreux](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/30729/mreux) and the Scryfall folks for the query!)

Comment: As for exceptions, only indestructible and hexproof appear on non-creature no -vehicle cards. Full list here https://scryfall.com/search?q=fo%3A%2F%5E%28hexproof%7Cindestructible%29%2F+-t%3A%2Fcreature%7Cvehicle%2F&unique=cards&as=grid&order=name

Comment: Good point, I was thinking only of stuff like flying and deathtouch. Indestructible and hexproof are (relatively) common on other types; deleted that section from the answer as it will probably get too confusing.

Comment: @mreux wither is retired but it appeared on Puncture Blast, and some of the other words can exist on other card types but there aren't printed examples, for instance how Firesong and Sunspeaker give red spells lifelink. A bit nitpicky, and not currently relevant to the question, but still true.

Comment: Bit nitpicky, but "Super-Duper Death Ray" is an instant that has trample.  Admittedly, it's silver bordered, but still... :)

Comment: @DenisS The [equivalent competitive legal cards](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=479637) use a different templating so I think we can ignore that one :-)

Comment: I know there's some creatures that give your instants and sorceries Lifelink. Are there any of them that have Lifelink as a standalone card?